# Default value in dropdown <select> (symfony)

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony-forms, symfony-3.3, symfony3.x

I have this code in the form:

```
$formShipping->add('shippingType', EntityType::class, array('mapped' => false, 'required' => true,'placeholder' => 'Select a shipping method', 'label' => 'Shipping Method', 'class' => 'BackendBundle\Entity\Shipping', 'choice_label' => 'shipdesc',
                'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('s')
                        ->where('s.active = :active')
                        ->orderBy('s.shipdesc', 'ASC')
                        ->setParameter('active', true);
                }, 'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control')));
```

And this code in twig:

```
{{ form_row(form.shippingType, {value: "1" })}}
```

But the result is this:

[image]

I review with the inspector:

[image]

What is the problem??

Comment: your code looks good and seems like it should work. Can you add the html from "view source" instead of the inspector. Sometime the inspector adds things to the HTML that aren't in the actual source.

Comment: Are you using a Javascript plugin to change the way the <select> looks? You might have to refresh it once it's loaded.